# Random time and date between 2 date values

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a php script (or line of code) to echo a random time and date between 2 dates, eg

2012-12-24 13:03

which would be between my chosen dates of 1st October 2012 and 1st Jan 2013.

Any ideas how best to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is easy - you need a random timestamp. Then from random timestamp you will be able extract the time...

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Do you want to include october 1st and Jan 1st in the random dates or only between them?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Easy :) Just choose 2 random dates, convert to EPOCH, and random between these 2 values :)

[EPOCH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) - The time since 1/1/1970, in seconds.
You can use the [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to make date-strings turn into epoch time, and the [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function to make it the other way back.

```
function rand_date($min_date, $max_date) {
    /* Gets 2 dates as string, earlier and later date.
       Returns date in between them.
    */

    $min_epoch = strtotime($min_date);
    $max_epoch = strtotime($max_date);

    $rand_epoch = rand($min_epoch, $max_epoch);

    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $rand_epoch);
}
```

Comment: this should be a comment. answers should have more 'meat'

Comment: @Infinity This was the way I did it in the end, thanks for all the answers.

Comment: LoL! Why I didn't think it first. Awesome! +1

Comment: I can only get this to go back up to seven seconds when I wanted it to go for two weeks. Why would this happen?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to include October 1st, but not include Jan 1st...

```
$start = strtotime("2012-10-01 00:00:00");
$end =  strtotime("2012-12-31 23:59:59");

$randomDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", rand($start, $end));

echo $randomDate;
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to define a resolution, for example one minute, or three minutes or 15 seconds or one and a half day or what not. The randomness should be applied on the whole period, I've choosen one minute here for exemplary purposes (there are 132480 minutes in your period).

```
$start    = new Datetime('1st October 2012');
$end      = new Datetime('1st Jan 2013');
$interval = new DateInterval('PT1M'); // Resolution: 1 Minute
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
$random   = new RandomIterator($period);

list($result) = iterator_to_array($random, false) ? : [null];
```

This for example gives:

```
class DateTime#7 (3) {
  public $date =>
  string(19) "2012-10-16 02:06:00"
  public $timezone_type =>
  int(3)
  public $timezone =>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

You can [find the `RandomIterator` here](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/getting-n-random-elements-out-of-an-iterator-randomiterator/). Without it, it will take a little longer (ca. 1.5 the number of iterations compared to the example above) using:

```
$count    = iterator_count($period);
$random   = rand(1, $count);

$limited = new LimitIterator(new IteratorIterator($period), $random - 1, 1);
$limited->rewind();
$result = $limited->current();
```

I also tried with seconds, but that would take quite long. You probably want first to find a random day (92 days), and then some random time in it.

Also I've run some tests and I could not find any benefit in using `DatePeriod` so far as long as you're on common resolutions like seconds:

```
$start    = new Datetime('1st October 2012');
$end      = new Datetime('1st Jan 2013');

$random   = new DateTime('@' . mt_rand($start->getTimestamp(), $end->getTimestamp()));
```

or minutes:

```
/**
 * @param DateTime $start
 * @param DateTime $end
 * @param int|DateInterval $resolution in Seconds or as DateInterval
 * @return DateTime
 */
$randomTime = function (DateTime $start, DateTime $end, $resolution = 1) {

    if ($resolution instanceof DateInterval) {
        $interval   = $resolution;
        $resolution = ($interval->m * 2.62974e6 + $interval->d) * 86400 + $interval->h * 60 + $interval->s;
    }

    $startValue = floor($start->getTimestamp() / $resolution);
    $endValue   = ceil($end->getTimestamp() / $resolution);
    $random     = mt_rand($startValue, $endValue) * $resolution;

    return new DateTime('@' . $random);
};

$random = $randomTime($start, $end, 60);
```

Comment: + nice hacking creating your own `seek` on `Traversable` with `IteratorIterator` +  `LimitIterator`

Comment: @Baba: Yes, but this iterates twice. Maybe you know some kewl algorithm to get a random value from a set of unknown elements without knowing the size of the set upfront.

Comment: its not possible without `loop` what can be done is to limit the loop to only one by extending `DatePeriod` to implement `ArrayIterator` that way you would eliminate the duplicate loop and just use `rand` with `ArrayIterator::seek` to get rand date

Comment: @Baba Then I have the full copy of all DateTime objects (check: [`CachingIterator`](http://php.net/CachingIterator) with full cache flag set, too). Isn't there some clever mathematical formula? Somthing like storing only the half of all element of the set or somewhat?

Comment: they are so may algorithmic i can implement but they all require length ... But i think am about to figure a clear way to resolve the above code without multiple loops ... one moment

Comment: @Baba: I now used the new [`RandomIterator` with Reservoir sampling](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/getting-n-random-elements-out-of-an-iterator-randomiterator/) but it's a bit expensive for this example (at least at the resolution of one second it makes no sense at all, other resolutions are critical as well, so not a good example to use it here from a practical standpoint). However it works without counting in advance ;)

Comment: Nice one ... start firs first project in git on Iterators ... or `RandomIterator` should find a place there soon

Answer (score 2):

so crazy it just may worK

```
function randomDate($start_date, $end_date)
{
//make timetamps
$min = strtotime($start_date);
$max = strtotime($end_date);

//random date
$rand_date = rand($min, $max);

//format it
return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $rand_date);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code to accomplish this:

```
$randDate=date('Y-m-d', mt_rand(strtotime('2012-10-01'), strtotime('2013-01-01')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's something

```
$date_start = strtotime('1 October 2012');
$date_end = strtotime('1 January 2013');
$rand_date = rand($date_start, $date_end);
echo(date('d.m.Y H:i', $rand_date));
```