# Generate 50 random-duration time intervals in MySQL or PHP, between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, date-range

I am trying to insert a random list of 50 datetime ranges into a MySQL database. These date ranges must be between a specific start and end date, and they must be adjacent and ordered by time.

Heres an example of the DB table I am trying to generate between **2014-09-01 00:00:00** - **2014-10-12 23:59:59**:

```
start_time                     end_time
--------------------------------------------------------
2014-09-01 00:00:00            2014-09-01 02:45:12  
2014-09-01 02:45:13            2014-09-01 04:12:33
2014-09-01 04:12:34            2014-09-02 12:12:20
....
2014-10-12 23:30:13            2014-10-12 23:59:59
```

I am unsure if this can be done solely in MySQL or whether I would need a PHP script. Generating a list of random dates between dates is fine, its splitting the randomness up evenly between 50 entries that has me confused.

Can this be done in MySQL and if so what would be the preferred method?

**Edit:**
To explain my question better, I have a date range which i need to generate a list of 50 start and end dates between. I should have mentioned that, like my example, the start date must be immediately the next second after the previous end date.

Comment: So, you really want a set of 50, monotonically increasing, non-overlapping time intervals between two given date times, such that the intervals touch on preceding boundaries. Graphically: `[[...][.][......][..][.......][................][.]<etc>]'`.  If so, I really didn't get that from your original question, especially your title.  Am I off here?

Comment: @bishop that is exactly what I'm looking for but more eloquently put.

Comment: Ok, I've posted a MySQL solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in MySQL.  The general algorithm for N intervals is:

1. Generate N-1 distinct, random timestamps between your begin time + 1 second and your end time - 2 seconds.
2. Sort them, oldest to youngest. These are your interval begin points.
3. Subtract one second to from each end point to get the prior interval's start point.

**Example**
[Install these generator views](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2011-07-30/mysql-row-generator#mysql_generator_code), then:

```
CREATE TABLE times (id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,begin_time DOUBLE NOT NULL,end_time DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);
INSERT INTO times (begin_time) SELECT @low bp UNION SELECT s.bp FROM (SELECT t.bp FROM (SELECT @low + FLOOR(RAND() * (@high-@low)) bp FROM generator_256 JOIN (SELECT @low := UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-09-01 00:00:00'), @high := UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-10-12 23:59:59')) init LIMIT 49) t ORDER by bp) s;
UPDATE times JOIN (SELECT curr.id, curr.begin_time, (SELECT next.begin_time-1 FROM times next WHERE next.id=curr.id+1) end_time FROM times curr) g ON g.id = times.id SET times.end_time = COALESCE(g.end_time, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-10-12 23:59:59'));
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(begin_time), FROM_UNIXTIME(end_time) FROM times;
+---------------------------+-------------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME(begin_time) | FROM_UNIXTIME(end_time) |
+---------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2014-09-01 00:00:00       | 2014-09-02 13:32:45     |
| 2014-09-02 13:32:46       | 2014-09-03 07:57:24     |
| 2014-09-03 07:57:25       | 2014-09-04 17:34:01     |
| 2014-09-04 17:34:02       | 2014-09-04 19:46:25     |
| 2014-09-04 19:46:26       | 2014-09-05 17:44:48     |
                           ...
| 2014-10-10 18:39:47       | 2014-10-11 05:11:13     |
| 2014-10-11 05:11:14       | 2014-10-11 11:27:29     |
| 2014-10-11 11:27:30       | 2014-10-12 13:03:02     |
| 2014-10-12 13:03:03       | 2014-10-12 17:55:54     |
| 2014-10-12 17:55:55       | 2014-10-12 19:11:11     |
| 2014-10-12 19:11:12       | 2014-10-12 23:59:59     |
+---------------------------+-------------------------+
50 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Explanation**
Let's break these down, step by step.  To generate rows in MySQL, you have to use a [generator view](http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2011-07-30/mysql-row-generator#mysql_generator_code). A generator view just gives you N rows each time you ask for it.  As an example, to get 49 rows (N-1):

```
SELECT * FROM generator_256 LIMIT 49;
```

To generate a single random number between two other numbers in MySQL, use the random number formula `low + (RAND() * (high-low))`.  This formula combined with the generator view gets us the 49 begin points we want for step 1:

```
SELECT (@low + FLOOR(RAND() * (@high-@low))) AS bp FROM generator_256 LIMIT 49;
```

(I'm using session variables here to keep the SQL simple. They'll become part of the query in a just a bit.  If you want to debug, remember bp is a timestamp, so FROM_UNIXTIME(bp) will show you a human-friendly format.)

Now, to sort the list, use a sub-query: if you sort the generated query, you'll get random values clustered near the beginning time.  So, to mostly fulfill step 2:

```
SELECT t.bp FROM (SELECT @low + FLOOR(RAND() * (@high-@low)) bp FROM generator_256 LIMIT 49) t ORDER by t.bp;
```

Now, it starts to get tricky.  For any given row, we want to fill the end time with one second less than the next row's beginning time.  While there are a couple of ways of going about it, I think the cleanest to understand is one that uses the destination table (or a copy of it) to store our generated begin points.  (Note I've initialized values for @low and @high here as well as included the beginning point in the list):

```
CREATE TABLE times (id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,begin_time DOUBLE NOT NULL,end_time DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);
INSERT INTO times (begin_time) SELECT @low bp UNION SELECT s.bp FROM (SELECT t.bp FROM (SELECT @low + FLOOR(RAND() * (@high-@low)) bp FROM generator_256 JOIN (SELECT @low := UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-09-01 00:00:00'), @high := UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-10-12 23:59:59')) init LIMIT 49) t ORDER by bp) s;
```

Finally, we can add the end times using a joined update.

```
UPDATE times JOIN (SELECT curr.id, curr.begin_time, (SELECT next.begin_time-1 FROM times next WHERE next.id=curr.id+1) end_time FROM times curr) g ON g.id = times.id SET times.end_time = COALESCE(g.end_time, UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-10-12 23:59:59'));
```

In my examples here, I've left off two things:

1. I'm ignoring the need to start one second after the begin and two seconds prior to the end.  Thus, it's possible that one of your random values could equal the begin or end point, which would violate your stated need.  You can add these constraints by using the MySQL `INTERVAL` operator.
2. In a truely random system, a long sequence of identical values is just as likely as a jumbled one.  Eg, in binary, 000000000000000 is just as likely as 111111111111111 is just as likely as 0101010111101011.  That means we could get 50 identical dates out of our query.  You can get around this by generating a whole bunch of random times (1000s, maybe) and culling from that.

Comment: Wow, Thanks bishop. I've re-read the generator view link you sent and it's making sense. Managed to create the 50 rows that I needed. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

You can [generate random dates using php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14186825/1275255) and add some function to check additional date ranges:

You must load your internal date ranges: (I use an array but you will load from DB)

```
$ranges = array(
    0 => array('start' => '2014-09-01 00:00:00', 'end' => '2014-09-01 02:45:12'),
    1 => array('start' => '2014-09-01 02:45:13', 'end' => '2014-09-01 04:12:33'),
    2 => array('start' => '2014-09-01 04:12:34', 'end' => '2014-09-02 12:12:20'),
    3 => array('start' => '2014-10-12 23:30:13', 'end' => '2014-10-12 23:59:59')
);
```

Function to check a date is in $ranges array:

```
function date_in_range($date_ranges,$rand_epoch){
    foreach($date_ranges as $date){
        $min_epoch = strtotime($date['start']);
        $max_epoch = strtotime($date['end']);
        if($rand_epoch >= $min_epoch && $rand_epoch <= $max_epoch){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Modified function to generate a random date:

```
function rand_date($min_date, $max_date, $internal_ranges) {
    /* Gets 2 dates as string, earlier and later date.
       Returns date in between them.
    */

    $min_epoch = strtotime($min_date);
    $max_epoch = strtotime($max_date);

    $rand_epoch = rand($min_epoch, $max_epoch);

   // If date is not in internal range, get another random date again:
    while(!date_in_range($internal_ranges,$rand_epoch)){
        $rand_epoch = rand($min_epoch, $max_epoch);
    }

    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $rand_epoch);
}

// Testing
print rand_date('2014-09-01 00:00:00','2014-10-12 23:59:59',$ranges);
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan. The tricky bit is generating random date ranges inbetween the main date range

Comment: Let me change my answer

Comment: If you want a PHP solution, I strongly encourage using [Fazinotto's Faker, which has a datetimeBetween() method](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#fakerproviderdatetime).

Comment: I just modified my answer, maybe is not the best performance... but is a solution.